# Is it possible to use deeplearning with spark (with a distributed databases as HDFS or Cassandra)?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, convergence

If it is possible, will it be really useful or the model will end up converging very early(with a typical optimum learning rate) ? Any content on this topic will be helpful for me.

Comment: For those not familiar with it, could you explain what "spark" is?

Comment: Apache Spark is open source, general-purpose distributed computing engine used for processing and analyzing a large amount of data. Just like Hadoop MapReduce, it also works with the system to distribute data across the cluster and process the data in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use deep learning architecture with Apache Spark now. Databricks have Spark-deep-learning which is a pipeline based in python and uses tensorflow and keras.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-deep-learning

You can check this. There is also BigDL by Intel analytics.
https://github.com/intel-analytics/BigDL